# Why I receive the error message when trying to access user data from the context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I need to access the user data from AuthDataContext inside App.jsx, the problem is I receive an error message, most probably because there is no access of the user context into App.jsx . Can someone see the mistake?

```
// Authentication Context

import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  EmailAuthCredential,
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthDataContext = createContext(null);

export default function AuthContext({ children }) {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      return setUser(user);
    } else {
      return setUser(null);
    }
  });

  return (
    <AuthDataContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthDataContext.Provider>
  );
}

// App

...other code

import ContextProviders from "./context/Context-Config";
import AuthContext from "./context/Auth-Context";
import { AuthDataContext } from "./context/Auth-Context";


export default function App() {

...other code


  const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthDataContext);
 

  return (
    <AuthContext>
      <ContextProviders
        configs={configs}
        genres={{
          genresMovie,
          genresTv,
        }}
        bookmarkShows={{
          bookmarkShows,
          setBookmarkShows,
          bookmarksTrace,
          setBookmarksTrace,
        }}
        movies={{
          trendingMovies,
          popularMovies,
          topRatedMovies,
          upcomingMovies,
          nowPlayingMovies,
        }}
        tv={{
          popularTv,
          topRatedTv,
          airingTodayTv,
          onTheAirTv,
        }}
      >
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <SearchBar />
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </ContextProviders>
    </AuthContext>
  );
}
```

**the error message : **

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'user' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is null.
at App (App.jsx:42:1)

Maybe I organized the context incorrectly? Why I can't access data into my App.jsx if I wrapped it into AuthContext?

Comment: You're accessing `useContext(..)` in the `App` component, but `App` is not inside an `AuthDataContext` provider so it will receive the default context value (`null`). [There's a brief mention of this in the React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useContext#my-component-doesnt-see-the-value-from-my-provider)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I wrapped with AuthContext inside my App.jsx:

```
<AuthContext>
  <ContextProviders
    configs={configs}
    genres={{
      genresMovie,
      genresTv,
    }}
    bookmarkShows={{
      bookmarkShows,
      setBookmarkShows,
      bookmarksTrace,
      setBookmarksTrace,
    }}
    movies={{
      trendingMovies,
      popularMovies,
      topRatedMovies,
      upcomingMovies,
      nowPlayingMovies,
    }}
    tv={{
      popularTv,
      topRatedTv,
      airingTodayTv,
      onTheAirTv,
    }}
  >
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <SearchBar />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </ContextProviders>
</AuthContext>
```

The solution was to move AuthContext into index.js and wrap there the Router, which by the way contains the app component as well:

```
    import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./route-config";

import AuthContext from "./context/Auth-Context";

import App from "./App";

import "./assets/styles/index.scss";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContext>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AuthContext>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```